# Problem with SLD Style definition - Filters in Rules

Tags: geoserver, sld, filter, rule

I created a style in QGIS, exported in SLD and imported in geoserver. However validating throws me errors. I tried a lot of variants according to geoserver documentation and stackexchange solutions without any luck.
Am I missing something basic?

Errors:

```
line 11: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:And'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Symbolizer}' is expected.  
line 36: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Symbolizer}' is expected.  
line 70: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Symbolizer}' is expected.  
line 97: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Symbolizer}' is expected.  
line 130: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'ogc:Filter'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/se":Symbolizer}' is expected.
```

Here is my file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>WSGZF</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>WSGZF</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name></se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>500000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ZONE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Zone I</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Z_N_1</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>LL</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ff9c9c</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name></se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>500000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ZONE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Zone II</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ZONE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Zone IIA</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Z_N_1</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>LL</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>

            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffb5</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name></se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>500000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ZONE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Zone IIB</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Z_N_1</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>LL</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>              
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffd6</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name></se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>500000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:Or>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ZONE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Zone III</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ZONE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Zone IIIA</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              </ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Z_N_1</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>LL</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#deffd6</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name></se:Name>
          <se:MaxScaleDenominator>500000</se:MaxScaleDenominator>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>

                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>ZONE</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>Zone IIIB</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Z_N_1</ogc:PropertyName>
                  <ogc:Literal>LL</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>              
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffffff</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill-opacity">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing versions of the [styling languages](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/reference/index.html) - most of your document is using [Symbology Encoding (SE)](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/se) which needs to use [Filter Encoding Specification (FES)](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/filter) 2.0. However, you have used Filters v 1.0 in your document which is why GeoServer doesn't like the document.

So the 1st thing to do is add `xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"` and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0
   http://schemas.opengis.net/filter/2.0.0/filterAll.xsd"` to your declaration, then you need to change the filters to reflect the new standard, so for example `<ogc:PropetrtyName>` becomes `<fes:ValueReference>`. So your first filter becomes

```
    <fes:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <fes:And>
          <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <fes:ValueReference>ZONE</fes:ValueReference>
              <ogc:Literal>Zone I</ogc:Literal>
            </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <fes:ValueReference>Z_N_1</fes:ValueReference>
              <ogc:Literal>LL</ogc:Literal>
            </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        </fes:And>
      </fes:Filter>
```

Comment: Thank you Ian for fast response. However it looks it din't helped. I am still getting errors. 'line 18: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'fes:Filter'. One of '{"opengis.net/se":Symbolizer}' is expected.'

Comment: I ended up with overwriting the whole style into CSS. Now everything works,